# Bulma - How can I update / access secondary and tertiary color variables?

Tags: bulma

I have this code:

```
// My Theme Colors
$green: #45CB85;

// Bulma Overrides
$primary: $green;
$navbar-item-hover-background-color: $primary-light;
$navbar-item-hover-color: $primary-dark;

// Import Bulma
@import "bulma/utilities/_all"; // includes the functions file
@import "bulma/base/_all";
@import "bulma/elements/_all";
@import "bulma/form/_all";
@import "bulma/components/_all";
@import "bulma/grid/_all";
@import "bulma/helpers/_all";
@import "bulma/layout/_all";
```

My expectation is that, now that $primary has been set to my custom color, then $primary-light and $primary-dark would update too because they are based on $primary, according to the [Bulma documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/).

But these declarations don't seem to change anything on my site:

```
$navbar-item-hover-background-color: $primary-light;
$navbar-item-hover-color: $primary-dark;
```

I've even tried updating these colors by referencing the function in the Bulma docs, but this doesn't work either:

```
// My Theme Colors
$green: #45CB85;

// Bulma Overrides
$primary: $green;
$primary-light: findLightColor($primary); // the Bulma function for creating primary light
$navbar-item-hover-background-color: $primary-light;
$navbar-item-hover-color: $primary-dark;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think yo have to use Sass (not vanilla CSS) to change the colors.

From https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-sass-cli/#6-add-your-own-bulma-styles. In my own experience, I put them before @import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";

```
// Set your brand colors
$purple: #8A4D76;
$pink: #FA7C91;
$brown: #757763;
$beige-light: #D0D1CD;
$beige-lighter: #EFF0EB;

// Update Bulma's global variables
$family-sans-serif: "Nunito", sans-serif;
$grey-dark: $brown;
$grey-light: $beige-light;
$primary: $purple;
$link: $pink;
$widescreen-enabled: false;
$fullhd-enabled: false;

// Update some of Bulma's component variables
$body-background-color: $beige-lighter;
$control-border-width: 2px;
$input-border-color: transparent;
$input-shadow: none;

// Import only what you need from Bulma
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/container.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/title.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/section.sass";
```

if you want to *add* new color names, you will to also map them

```
// 5. Add new color variables to the color map.
@import "../sass/utilities/derived-variables";
$addColors: (
  "twitter":($twitter, $twitter-invert),
  "linkedin": ($linkedin, $linkedin-invert),
  "github": ($github, $github-invert)
);
$colors: map-merge($colors, $addColors);

// 6. Import the rest of Bulma
@import "../bulma";
```